# Any tips on beating the destroyer with melee class and some accessory suggestions?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm having troubles beating the Destroyer with full titanium armor (melee) and the Daedalus storm bow. I even have Ice Wings, Ice Whip, and Terraspark boosts. So please, any tips on beating the Destroyer in classic? If any one could help me.

Comment: thanks pinckerman for correcting the daedalus storm bow

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this on a different question. It was to make a flat U shape that is 50 - 30 blocks high and long to block lasers. It's in the air 250-300 blocks from a flat ground, and what I used a nimbus rod to hit the destroyer and the ice whip to kill the probes. So put more solutions for many more ways to kill the Destroyer.

Comment: Pink Killer didnt change anything he just it so he would get credit

Comment: There's no "credit" for editing. But they did fix your punctuation. The answer history still shows your original.